# Coudnt call the array in main-activity

Tags: java, android, arrays

I've created 2 arrays in my string.xml. But when i call the strings in my MainActivity.java it says "array could not be retrieved or not a field"

can anyone help me to fix this. thank you

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="place_type">
    <item>hospitals</item>
    <item>health</item>
    <item>doctor</item>
    <item>pharmacy</item>
</string-array>

 <string-array name="place_type_name">
    <item>HOSPITALS</item>
    <item>HEALTH</item>
    <item>DOCTOR</item>
    <item>PHARMACY</item>
</string-array>
```

MainActivity.java

```
   // Array of place types
    mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type);

    // Array of place type names
    mPlaceTypeName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type_name);
```

Comment: make sure you have imported the correct R (not android.R)

Comment: Check whether you've placed the values file in correct (qualified)  folder

Comment: what is mPlaceType and mPlaceTypeName is it String Array ?

Comment: if mPlaceType and mPlaceTypeName are String Array then your code is absolutely correct please try to clean and run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps :

1] make sure you have imported the right R class. it is a common phenomenon to import android.R instead of your project's R.

2] after checking 1], clean and rebuild your application

Also put fetching array coding part either in `onCreate()` or use your `MainActivity` `context` of that class with getResources() else you probably get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thank you :) but how do I import my R??

Comment: your package name e.g. import com.example.R